# In Prestashop, how can I display category with its own products in a separate page?

Tags: php, smarty, categories, prestashop

In Prestashop 1.5.6.1 (http://www.tocgiaonline.vn), I need to display these things:

1. Homepage with Featured Products, New Products and Special Product
2. Category page with its own products
3. Product page for details

But I cannot find how to resolve section (2) anywhere, although looked up over Prestashop documents and do some search in Google. I write my questions here to look for a guidance how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please explain it clearly?

Comment: No, I cannot have a Category Page which display all products belongs to. For example, when you click to menu item "Tip Hair", I need it show a page with products belongs to category "Tip Hair". Now, it's Page Not Found error.